# What is the python way to avoid a default argument as a list of Nones?

Tags: python

I have two filenames as input arguments. Both filenames go through the same process, and their default values are `None`. I write my function like this:

```
import logging

def my_func(filename_list=[None]*2):
    for i in filename_list:
         if i is None:
             logging.info('One filename is None')
         else:
             # do stuff
```

Is there a better way to do it in python instead of using `[None]*2`?

Comment: It's generally not a pythonic way to define mutable default value (Scroll down [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) to *Important warning*). Set default to `None` and add a condition in function body.

Comment: If you want to take two filenames as input arguments, then why are you using a list? The *whole point* of a list is to have any number of values (including none)

Comment: ＠Alexander The reason to have a list is that the input could be `[None, None]`, `[filename1, None]`, `[None, filename2]`, or `[filename1, filename2]`. And I can not switch the order of `filename1` and `filename2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `None` as the default value. You can create a list of `None` inside the file.

```
def my_func(filename_list=None):
    if filename_list is None:
        filename_list = [None, None]

    for i in filename_list:
        ...
```

What is special about a list of 2 `Nones`, though? If `my_func` *always* takes a list of 2 filenames, I would recommend just passing them explicitly:

```
def my_func(file1=None, file2=None):
     for i in [file1, file2]:
         ...
```

Otherwise, an empty list would seem reasonable:

```
def my_func(filename_list=None):
    if file_name_list is None:
        filename_list = []
    for i in filename_list:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way is:

```
import logging

def my_func(first_filename, second_filename):
    file_names = [first_filename, second_filename]
    for i in filename_list:
         if i is None:
             logging.info('One filename is None')
         else:
             # do stuff
```

If you know you have 2 files for sure each call, do not pass a list as argument. There is no point.